# How to change VS2008 source control temporarily from VSS to Mercurial?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mercurial, visual-sourcesafe

At my new place of employment, I am working on a solution in Visual Studio 2008 whose source control has been Visual SourceSafe 2005.  For a lot of reasons that are probably not relevant here, the developers need temporarily to work disconnected from VSS (and from each other, which will work out fine in this case).  We are not allowed to check in or pull from VSS right now.

Since there's no way I'm working without source control, my idea was to set up Mercurial on my machine and use it as source control for the project until we will be going back to VSS.  The VSS control files can stick around as part of the project.  I have the VisualHg extension installed.  From the command line, I created my hg repository.  When I try to load the solution, though, one of two things happens, depending on the value of the "Autoselect VisualHG for Mercurial solutions" option for VisualHg:

1. (Autoselect on) When loading the project, I get a message saying, "The active solution or project is controlled by a different source control plug-in than the one you have selected.  If you change the source control plugin, the active solution or project will be closed.  Do you wish to continue?"  If I select Yes, of course the solution closes.  If I select No, the solution loads with VSS source control active.
2. (Autoselect off) The project loads with VSS source control active.  Trying to change the active plug-in to VisualHG (from Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection) results in the same message as above.

Is there a way I can easily (preferably without messing with the .sln or .csproj files directly) use Mercurial instead of VSS here, knowing that I will have to switch back to VSS in a few days?  No, dropping VSS entirely is not an option at this time (I wish it was).  Also, upgrading the project to VS2010 is not an option at this time.

Thank you!

Comment: I would just use Visual Studio as if you have no source control and use Tortoise or something to check in to Hg until you have to go back to VSS

Comment: @antlersoft Good point -- that's exactly what I have started doing in the few minutes since posting this question.  I'm a creature of habit, though, liking my IDE integration for good or ill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not what you asked, but one option would be to create a VSS database on your own machine and use that until the real VSS is available again.  Using VSS on your own system would involve many of the same steps as using another SCC tool so there might not be any significant advantage to using VSS locally over using Mercurial.

In Visual Studio 2008 you can use File | Source Control | Change Source Control to break the binding between your local copy of the Solution and Project (or Projects) and Visual SourceSafe.  In that dialog, select all the entries and click on Unbind.  That should address your "... controlled by a different source control plug-in ..." problem.

When it's time to switch back to VSS you can either throw away your local copy and start over with a fresh copy from VSS (if there's nothing local you want to check back into VSS) or you can use the same dialog to Bind your project back to VSS.

Or, if you're not confident about doing a Bind you could start over with a fresh copy from VSS, then overwrite your local files with the modified copies from Mercurial and then check those changed files out-from and back-into VSS.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I am not as familiar with VSS as with some other source control systems.  Wouldn't I need a VSS server license of some kind to install on my machine, or if I have the client, do I somehow have the server?  That said, there actually is no pristine copy of the code from VSS; one of the problems that led to the current situation is that the bindings in the main solution were pointing to incorrect locations.  My copy is now the fixed/merged copy with all the changes we need in one place (after some time spent with diff, patch, and kdiff3).

Comment: @Andrew my recollection is that Visual Studio 2008 Standard included a client license for Visual SourceSafe _and_ VSS server (perhaps just a personal or small team license for the server?)  But I can't find anything that says that explicitly.  The [VisualStudio2008-ProductComparison-v1.08.pdf](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7940) document isn't very clear.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of just unbinding everything in VSS then switching the plugin.  That actually worked quite nicely, and the bindings were all going to have to change when we returned to VSS anyway.  Thanks for your help, even if you didn't think it was what I was asking.